# Barring 1784, when has UK Parliament's legal sovereignty over-ridden the electorate's political sovereignty?

Tags: united-kingdom

*An Introduction to the Study of the Law of the Constitution* was first published in 1885, but I quote the 1915 8 edn.  [p. 250 of this transcribed online PDF](http://oll-resources.s3.amazonaws.com/titles/1714/Dicey_0125_EBk_v6.0.pdf). Here's [scan of original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIV7C.jpg).

Other than Pitt in 1784, already quoted below, when else did UK Parliament's legal sovereignty trample and overpowere the electorate's political sovereignty?

> The true answer to the objection thus raised appears to be that the observance of the
>   main and the most essential of all constitutional rules, the rule, that is to say, requiring
>   the annual meeting of Parliament, is ensured, without any necessity for Parliamentary
>   action, by the temporary character of the Mutiny Act, and that the power of
>   Parliament to compel obedience to its wishes by refusing to pass the Act is so
>   complete that the mere existence of the power has made its use unnecessary. In matter
>   of fact, no Ministry has since the Revolution of 1689 ever defied the House of
>   Commons, unless the Cabinet could confide in the support of the country, or, in other
>   words, could count on the election of a House which would support the policy of the
>   government. To this we must add, that in the rare instances in which a Minister has
>   defied the House, the refusal to pass the Mutiny Act has been threatened or
>   contemplated. Pitt's victory over the Coalition is constantly cited as a proof that
>   Parliament cannot refuse to grant supplies or to pass an Act necessary for the
>   discipline of the army. Yet any one who studies with care the great “Case of the
>   Coalition” will see that it does not support the dogma for which it is quoted. Fox and
>   his friends did threaten and did intend to press to the very utmost all the legal powers
>   of the House of Commons. They failed to carry out their intention solely because they
>   at last perceived that the majority of the House did not represent the will of the
>   country. What the “leading case” shows is, that the Cabinet, when supported by the
>   Crown, and therefore possessing the power of dissolution, can defy the will of a
>   House of Commons if the House is not supported by the electors. Here we come
>   round to the fundamental dogma of modem constitutionalism; **the legal sovereignty of
>   Parliament is subordinate to the political sovereignty of the nation**. This the
>   conclusion in reality established by the events of 1784. Pitt overrode the customs,
>   because he adhered to the principles, of the constitution. He broke through the
>   received constitutional understandings without damage to his power or reputation; he
>   might in all probability have in case of necessity broken the law itself with impunity.
>   For had the Coalition pressed their legal rights to an extreme length, the new
>   Parliament of 1784 would in all likelihood have passed an Act of Indemnity for

p. 261

> illegalities necessitated, or excused, by the attempt of an unpopular faction to drive
>   from power a Minister supported by the Crown, by the Peers, and by the nation.
>   However this may be, the celebrated conflict between Pitt and Fox lends no
>   countenance to the idea that a House of Commons supported by the country would not
>   enforce the morality of the constitution by placing before any Minister who defied its
>   precepts the alternative of resignation or revolution.

These quotes below can serve as context. p. 260.

> How, it may
>   be said, is the “point” to be fixed at which, in case of a conflict between the two
>   Houses, the Lords must give way, or the Crown ought to use its prerogative in the
>   creation of new Peers? The question is worth raising, because the answer throws great
>   light upon the nature and aim of the articles which make up our conventional code.
>   This reply is, that the point at which the Lords must yield or the Crown intervene is
>   properly determined by anything which conclusively shows that the House of
>   Commons represents on the matter in dispute the deliberate decision of the nation. The truth of this reply will 
>   hardly be questioned, but to admit that the deliberate 
>   decision of the electorate is decisive, is in fact to 
>   concede that the understandings as to the action of 
>   the House of Lords and of the Crown are, what we 
>   have found them to be, **rules meant to ensure the 
>   ultimate supremacy of the true political sovereign, or, 
>   in other words, of the electoral body.**<sup>1</sup>
>         By far the most striking example of the real sense 
>   attaching to a whole mass of constitutional conven-tions is found in a particular instance, which appears 
>   at first sight to present a marked exception to 
>   the general principles of constitutional morality.  A
>   Ministry placed in a minority by a vote of the Commons have, in accordance with
>   received doctrines, a right to demand a dissolution of Parliament.
>
> <sup>1</sup>  Cf. Bagehot, *English Constitution* (1872 ed.), pp. 25-27.

pp. 264-265

> The
>   personal influence of the Crown exists, not because acts of State are done formally in
>   the Crown's name, but because neither the legal sovereign power, namely Parliament,
>   nor the political sovereign, namely the nation, wishes that the reigning monarch
>   should be without personal weight in the government of the country.

Comment: Hello from a former resident of Swansea (briefly). I hope you can get out and about; it must be nice to be able to walk along the Gower beaches at the moment! I didn't vote to close but I think your question as it stands belongs on the Politics stack - the quotes involve too many nebulous value judgments to be answered within the scope of history. I am going to edit the question to leave only what I see as the historical part. If you don't like it, you can change it back

Comment: I didn't as I can see question has already been revised

Comment: Hopefully a useful tip: You have asked a number of questions about non-trivial "exceptions" to general rules. That is well and good, IMHO. But a way to ask is acknowledge the general rule, ask if exceptions have occurred, and why such exceptions might occur. Here, the "default" condition is that Parliament's sovereignty has been subordinate to the electorate's "popular" sovereignty. There have been notable exceptions to the rule. So you might state the general rule, cite one or two exceptions to the rule, and ask how they were able to occur in violation of the general rule.

Comment: @TomAu (1) What were the "notable exceptions to the rule"? (2) I can't "cite one or two exceptions to the rule" because I don't know any exceptions!

Comment: Until now, I did not realize the following: 1) You seem to have a "nose" for interesting topics, gathered from your readings. 2) You do not seem to fully understand what you have read. 3) Therefore you write potentially interesting questions without providing sufficient background to support them. Below, someone has given you the best answer you can reasonably hope for, despite your unclear question. The first line is "every moment of a Ministry [is] responsible to the House of Commons other than during an election: That could even be the premise of your question.

Comment: Cont'd. The answer goes on to cite exceptions to the above such as "Peterloo.", and suspending elections, followed by an "election of Victors," provided that they can avoid "hung Parliament. Here's a tip: Since this question is closed with only one answer, in your shoes, I would "practice" by writing a question to fit that answer. Once this is done, I will, in my "public defender" role, try to further improve a sufficiently improved question and try to get it reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every moment of a Ministry responsible to the House of Commons other than during an election.

The House of Commons and the Ministry (and for that matter the monarch's person) pay heed to the mood of the electorate.  They also heed the People.  They heed these groups chiefly to avoid the possibility of an interregnum (like [Cromwell's commonwealth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interregnum_(England))) or exregnum (a commonwealth without end).

The ministry have been quite willing to [Peterloo (ie: massacre)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterloo_Massacre) the People, a perfect example of the limited sovereignty of the People in the face of the force of the House of Common's army.

The ministry have been quite willing to suspend elections, and then face an [election of Victors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1945_United_Kingdom_general_election) where only one faction of the Ministry survived intact, and most of the ministry was eliminated in 1945.  World War II supplies an example of the House of Commons and ministry being unwilling to heed the Electorate (the electorate, after 1942, showing very strong signs of representing a Very Popular as in the European conception of The People’s position [cf: Orwell, Lion & Unicorn].)

More broadly, between every election, the House of Commons and the ministry are not threatened with an immediate dismissal by The Electorate.  The Electorate can only force its will on the House of Commons and thus the ministry at an election, or in a very hung parliament a by-election.  At all other times the House of Commons and the ministry are chiefly restricted by how much blood the sewer system can handle, and secondarily restricted by a series of conventions on not shooting non-Irish people in the United Kingdom.

---

#### Definitions:

- **Ministry**:
  The Prime Minister and those other persons (*Ministers*) holding Cabinet posts (or perhaps only senior Cabinet posts?). This is to distinguish from **the Government** which also comprises the *monarch's person*, the *civil service*, and the *armed forces*.
- **Monarch's Person**:
  The monarch regarded as a single individual with his/her personal wishes. This is to distinguish from the official, and ritual, roles that the *monarch* plays in a Westminster system, including specifically "*the monarch in council*".
- **House of Commons' Army**:
  The United Kingdom Army is properly regarded as owned (though not necessarily directed) by the House of Commons, rather than the Ministry, Government or Monarch more generally, because the House pays its wages and expenses with an annual bill of supply and discipline ([annual *Mutiny Act*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutiny_Acts)). The necessity for this bill to be passed annually is the empirical reason why the House is guaranteed to be called into session at least once a year.
- **Election of Victors**:
  An election following victory in war, limited to those who survive the political battles of the intervening period.  Most particularly the 1945 election in the UK who voted for a radical labourite policy set including free healthcare and mass public housing.
- **European conception of The People’s position**:
  From the French Revolution liberal continental Europe has relied on the common People as a mass body to supply conscripts and votes to support liberal democratic bourgeois states. The People constitute The Nation and justify the political Written Constitution with blood and rifles. As in a government or system of government could be unelected by mass democratic violence in a revolution.

Comment: I believe that the Peterloo Massacre really requires a link. Your example During- and Post-WW2 is also very obscure, and needs some tidying up.

Comment: Thanks. Will improve on this basis and link lion and unicorn also

Comment: @Swansea If you don't understand it then why did you accept it?

Comment: Thanks again. Can you please make your answer more simple? What's "the monarch's person"? "election of Victors"? What's Victor? What's "a Very Popular"? What's the "the European conception of The People position [cf: Orwell, Lion & Unicorn]"?

Comment: I've takne the liberty of attempting some definitions. Please correct any errors and/or reformat to your knowledge and taste. I believe this (once certified) adds  considerably to this answer.

Comment: My understanding is that despite the actual pay, the moral circumstances in the army -- especially in the past -- were motivated by its relationship to the monarch; hence the Great War's "For King and country" and Kitchener's "God save the King, join the army!". I've not seen (but it is also not my speciality) any references to the Commons' in such contexts.

Comment: @gktscrk kings shilling

Comment: @SamuelRussell: Good work. You might consider voting to reopen the question as well.

Comment: @gktscrk: I cannot vouch for the veracity, but my father used to state that beer steins had glass bottoms so that press-gangs couldn't slip *the King;'s shilling* into your beer unbeknownst. (Apparently, if your lips touched it you had formally "*accepted*" it, and were now a new recruit.) Congratulations! You can now be shot at for four pence a day.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I would feel obliged to rewrite the question before voting to reopen. I may do that to assist the initial questioner to develop their question asking skills.